# Hide subdirectory urls with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, joomla2.5, subdirectory

I'm sure some way or another this question is as old as the method itself but my challenge was to make

site.eu/subfolder/subfolder appear as subdomain.site.eu

I managed to figure that out on my own and got it to work. The code is following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.site.eu [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder1/subfolder2/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,P,NC]
```

The following issue is that in that adress, there is an app where you must log in.

After logging in, it will show subdomain.site.eu/subfolder1/subfolder2/content1

I have tried about 2-3 days to fix this but to no avail. I really hope somebody could help me out on this. IF there is any other info needed, please tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this in root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.site\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!subfolder1/subfolder2/).*)$ /subfolder1/subfolder2/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, been at this problem for days. :)